# php isset or greater than zero error

Tags: php, isset

I have the following code which I am trying to add a or operation to it but I am getting an error. Cant see what may be wrong. I want to get if it is set and greater than 0

```
  foreach($av as $day => $a) {
        if(isset($price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day]) || $price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day] > 0) {
                $arr_total += $price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day];
        } else {
                $errors[] = "No Set Price for $day";
        }
        // nice !
        if(isset($a[$ro['Room']['title']]) && $a[$ro['Room']['title']] < 1) {
                $no_rooms = true;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I think you need && not || and if the argument in isset is "" it is considered as set. So initialize that value to null initially or use another check

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($av as $day => $a) {
        if(isset($price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day]) && $price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day] > 0) {
                $arr_total += $price[$ro['Room']['id']][$r['Rate']['id']][$day];
        } else {
                $errors[] = "No Set Price for $day";
        }
        // nice !
        if(isset($a[$ro['Room']['title']]) && $a[$ro['Room']['title']] < 1) {
                $no_rooms = true;
        }
  }
```

try it